# How to switch Ruby versions on macOS using rbenv

Tags: ruby

I read a few Stack Overflow posts on a similar question, however, I cannot seem to fix my issue.

How do I get `ruby --version` to match the `rbenv version`?

```
rbenv version
2.6.5 (set by /Users/user/rubyonrails/lists/.ruby-version)

ruby --version
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
```

When I run

```
rbenv init
# Load rbenv automatically by appending
# the following to ~/.bash_profile:

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

I read a few other questions on Stack Overflow and modified my bash_profile accordingly, however it has not remedied the faulty `rbenv init` command.

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Django
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: What things did you try? Since you've tried things, we don't know what state is your rbenv environment is in. Have you tried removing the current rbenv along with its initialization in `~/.bash_profile` and reinstalling? What does `gem env` and `echo $PATH` output? Copy the output and paste it into your question, formatting it appropriately. Did you read the [rbenv installation documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation) especially steps 3 and 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only add these lines on your .bashrc

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
```

later use this command `$ rbenv install version-ruby`

and for switch use `$ rbenv global version-ruby`

(replace version-ruby for the number of the version.)